# How can I preview some data from xml to android studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, parsing, web-scraping

Data taken from an xml or json to the main activity using android studio? Or is it better to use webscraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about fetching a json object or array.. if you are then you should use the  Android volley library..

Here is a link on how to use volley

https://developer.android.com/training/volley

Comment: How do you use the volley library?

Comment: Check my answer.. I edited it ..  you can get values from the json Object or Json array.. and add a function to the onResponded function.. to populate your views

Comment: Then please tick my solution as the answers... Thanks